# Why is an explicit return required in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I have a small function like this:

```
tierRouter.get(
  '/:id',
  passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
  function (req, res) {
    Tier.findById(req.params.id, function (err, tier) {
      if (err) { res.json(500, { error: "Internal server error" }); }
      if (!tier) { return res.json(404, { error: "Not found" }); }
      res.json(200, clean(tier));
    });
  }
);
```

It looks for an object in my database and returns it as JSON to the user. If something goes wrong I get a `500` returned and if everything goes well I return `200` and the object. But when the object does not exist I return `404`. The only difference is that I have to write `return` before the `res.json` in the `404` case, or else Node will continue to `res.json(200, clean(tier));`.

I just don't understand why I have to add the `return` statement. Can someone explain that or kick me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need either early `return` or do a lot of `if/else` statements. otherewise, if you do `res.render()` or `res.json()` more than once on a request, you're going to get a `headers already sent` error and crash everything

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So in the case above, I should have an `return` for the `500` response too?